# Can i combine frameworks?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, uikit

I was wondering if im allowed to combine frameworks, specifically Bootstrap and UIKit.

For example could i use Bootstraps grid system but add in say the slideset component from UIKit?

And could any work i create using this method be sold?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine anything you like, though you need to make sure there are no conflicts.

You can sell any work you create so long as the licenses of the libraries/other work you use allow you to.